# What does SP means in Code Geass?

Tags: code-geass

In the second season (R2), they mention this term SP many times but I don't know what it means. Always wondered it's meaning. Does someone know it?

Comment: Can you give an example of where "SP" is used? I can't seem to remember this term being used anywhere.

Comment: @senshin I believe it's used in episode 12 of R2, but no indication of what it means (at least from that episode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of episode 12 of R2, when Rollo is castigating Sayoko for doing a poor job as Lelouch's double, the following conversation occurs:

> **Rollo:** それでもくノ一ですか。
> **Rollo:** And you call yourself a ninja?
>
> **Sayoko:** 正確には**ＳＰ**です。篠崎流３７代目の―
> **Sayoko:** To be precise, I'm an **SP**, the 37th of the Shinozaki line―

So what's an **SP**?

I don't think this is any sort of Code Geass-specific lingo. Given that it's an acronym, there's a lot of things it could stand for, but by far the most likely is **security police** (yes, Japanese has borrowed the phrase from English: セキュリティポリス *sekyuriti porisu*). The Japanese "security police" are sort of like the US's Secret Service - they're bodyguards for important people (cf. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Police_%28Japan%29)).

Given that the Ashfords are (or at least were) an important family of nobles, it isn't too surprising that they might have a bodyguard on staff, especially given that they're harboring an exiled prince and princess.